# Extracting outline of thick line

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

How can I draw outline of thick line such as one below in vector form? By vector form I mean some collection of Graphics primitives that's not Raster or Image.

```
Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[100], JoinForm["Round"], CapForm["Round"],
   Line[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}}]}, ImageSize -> 200]
```

[image]
<sub>(source: [yaroslavvb.com](http://yaroslavvb.com/upload/save/so-outlines.png))</sub>

Documentation has the following example for extracting outlines of text, but I haven't found a way to modify it to get outlines of `Line` objects

```
ImportString[ExportString[Style["M8", FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 72],"PDF"], "TextMode" -> "Outlines"]
```

I've [also tried](https://mathematica-bits.blogspot.com/2010/12/tiles-with-holes.html) doing `Rasterize` on the line object and subtracting a slightly smaller version from the alpha channel. That gives rasterization artifacts, and is too slow at 5 seconds per shape for `ImageSize->500`

also asked on mathgroup

**Update**
I've tried fitting spline through points you get from `MorphologicalPerimeter`. `ListCurvePathPlot` theoretically does it, but it breaks on pixel "staircase" pattern. To smooth the staircase one needs to find ordering of points around the curve. `FindCurvePath` seemed promising, but returned list of broken curves. `FindShortestTour` could also theoretically do this, but it took over a second on outline in a 20x20 pixel image. `ConvexHull` does perfect job on round parts, but cuts off the non-convex part.

Solution I finally ended up with was constructing nearest neighbor graph over perimeter points and using version 8 function `FindEulerianCycle` to find the ordering of pixels around the shape, then using `MovingAverage` to smooth out the staircase, followed by `ListCurvePathPlot` to create the spline object. It's not perfect, as there's still a remnant of "staircase" pattern whereas averaging too much will smooth out important corners. A better approach might break the shape into multiple convex shapes, use `ConvexHull`, then recombine. Meanwhile, here's what I'm using

```
getSplineOutline[pp_, smoothLen_: 2, interOrder_: 3] := (
   (* need to negate before finding perimeter to avoid border *)

   perim = MorphologicalPerimeter@ColorNegate@pp;
   points = 
    Cases[ArrayRules@SparseArray@ImageData[perim], 
     HoldPattern[{a_Integer, b_Integer} -> _] :> {a, b}];
   (* raster coordinate system is upside down, flip the points *)

   points = {1, -1} (# - {0, m}) & /@ points;
   (* make nearest neighbor graph *)

   makeEdges[point_] := {Sort[{point, #}]} & /@ 
     Nearest[DeleteCases[points, point], point];
   edges = Union[Flatten[makeEdges /@ points, 2]];
   graph = Graph[UndirectedEdge @@@ edges];
   tour = FindEulerianCycle[graph] // First;
   smoothed = MovingAverage[tour[[All, 1]], smoothLen];
   g = ListCurvePathPlot[smoothed, InterpolationOrder -> interOrder];
   Cases[g, BSplineCurve[___], Infinity] // First
   );

scale = 200;
pp = Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[scale/2], JoinForm["Round"], 
    CapForm["Round"], Line[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}}]}, 
   ImageSize -> scale];
Graphics[getSplineOutline[pp, 3, 3]]
```

[image]
<sub>(source: [yaroslavvb.com](http://yaroslavvb.com/upload/save/so-outlines2.png))</sub>

Comment: @Yaro I'm not sure of your expected output ("vector form"). Could you post a clarification? Tnx!

Comment: I think your text example is from Mma8 ... does not run on 7 :(

Comment: Added clarification. The example uses undocumented options, wasn't sure if it were 7 or 8, but it doesn't work for this problem anyway, only works for text

Comment: Pretty impressive - and quite a nice final result. It would be nice if we could just access the mma internals that generate the lines with EdgeForm and CapForm properties. It might be faster (in terms of computer time) to just rewrite these for yourself...

Comment: @Yaro Just in case you are still on this one. Check out the new (v8) **FilledCurve**

Answer (score 2):

It's a shame that `EdgeForm[]` (as stated in the docs) does not apply to `Line` objects. So the best we can do is either not use `Line[]` or to use a hack of some sort. The simplest I could think of is

```
Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[100], JoinForm["Round"], CapForm["Round"],
   Line[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}}], AbsoluteThickness[99], White, 
  Line[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}}]}, ImageSize -> 200]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I am not sure if this is worth, but here we go:  a method using image transformation, least squares and data clustering.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
(*Functions for Least Square Circle \
from  http://www.dtcenter.org/met/users/docs/write_ups/circle_fit.pdf*)


t[x_] := Plus[#, -Mean[x]] & /@ x;
Suu[x_] := Sum[i[[1]]^2, {i, t[x]}];
Svv[x_] := Sum[i[[2]]^2, {i, t[x]}];
Suv[x_] := Sum[i[[1]] i[[2]], {i, t[x]}];
Suvv[x_] := Sum[i[[1]] i[[2]]^2, {i, t[x]}];
Svuu[x_] := Sum[i[[2]] i[[1]]^2, {i, t[x]}];
Suuu[x_] := Sum[i[[1]]^3, {i, t[x]}];
Svvv[x_] := Sum[i[[2]]^3, {i, t[x]}];
s[x_] := Solve[{uc Suu[x] + vc Suv[x] == 1/2 (Suuu[x] + Suvv[x]), 
    uc Suv[x] + vc Svv[x] == 1/2 (Svvv[x] + Svuu[x])}, {uc, vc}];
(*Utility fun*)
ppfilterCoords[x_, k_] := Module[{ppflat},
   ppflat = 
    Flatten[Table[{i, j, ImageData[x][[i, j]]}, {i, k[[1]]}, {j, 
       k[[2]]}], 1];
   Take[#, 2] & /@ Select[ppflat, #[[3]] == 0 &]
   ];
(*Start*)
thk = 100;
pp = Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[100], JoinForm["Round"], 
   CapForm["Round"], Line[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}}]}, 
  ImageSize -> 300]
(*
pp=Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[thk],JoinForm["Round"],CapForm["Round"]\
,Line[{{0,0},{0,3},{1,3},{1,0}}]},ImageSize->300];
*)
pp1 = ColorNegate@MorphologicalPerimeter@pp;
(* Get vertex in pp3*)
pp3 = Binarize[ColorNegate@HitMissTransform[pp1,
     { {{1, -1}, {-1, -1}}, {{-1, 1}, {-1, -1}},
      {{-1, -1}, {1, -1}}, {{-1, -1}, {-1, 1}}}], 0];
k = Dimensions@ImageData@pp3;

clus = FindClusters[ppfilterCoords[pp3, k],(*get circles appart*)
   Method -> {"Agglomerate", "Linkage" -> "Complete"}, 
   DistanceFunction -> (If [EuclideanDistance[#1, #2] <= thk/2, 0, 
       EuclideanDistance[#1, #2]] &)]; 
(*Drop Spurious clusters*)
clus = Select[clus, Dimensions[#][[1]] > 10 &];
(*Calculate centers*)
centerOffset = Flatten[{uc, vc} /. s[#] & /@ clus, 1];
(*coordinates correction*)
center = {-1, 1} Plus[#, {0, k[[2]]}] & /@ -N[
     centerOffset + Mean /@ clus, 2];
Print["Circles Centers ", center];
(*get radius from coordinates. All radius are equal*)
radius = Max[Table[
     {Max[First /@ clus[[i]]] - Min[First /@ clus[[i]]],
      Max[Last /@ clus[[i]] - Min[Last /@ clus[[i]]]]}
     , {i, Length[clus]}]]/2;
Print["Circles Radius ", radius];

(*Now get the straight lines*)
(*horizontal lines*)
const = 30;(*a number of aligned pixels for line detection*)
ph = ColorNegate@
  HitMissTransform[ColorNegate@pp1, {Table[1, {const}]}];
(*vertical lines *)
pv = ColorNegate@
   HitMissTransform[ColorNegate@pp1, {Table[{1}, {const}]}];
(*if there are diagonal lines add patterns accordingy*)
(*coordinates correction function*)
corr[x_, k_] := {-1, 1} Plus[-x, {0, k[[2]]}];
dfunH[x_, y_] := Abs[x[[1]] - y[[1]]];
dfunV[x_, y_] := Abs[x[[2]] - y[[2]]];
(*Get clusters for horiz*)
clusH = FindClusters[ppfilterCoords[ph, k],(*get lines appart*)
   Method -> {"Agglomerate", "Linkage" -> "Complete"}, 
   DistanceFunction -> dfunH];
hlines = Table[{Line[{corr[First[i], k] + {1, const/2 - 1}, 
      corr[Last[i], k] + {1, -const/2 - 1}}]}, {i, clusH}];

clusV = FindClusters[ppfilterCoords[pv, k],(*get lines appart*)
   Method -> {"Agglomerate", "Linkage" -> "Complete"}, 
   DistanceFunction -> dfunV];
vlines = Table[{Line[{corr[First[i], k] - {const/2 - 1, 1}, 
      corr[Last[i], k] + {const/2 - 1, -1}}]}, {i, clusV}];
Graphics[{vlines, hlines, 
  Table[Circle[center[[i]], radius], {i, Length@clus}]}]
```

[image]

[image]

**Edit**

Update:

[image]

Comment: Wow...I now think I should've specified line limit for the answer :P

Comment: it's OK, I think this approach would take quite a bit of work to make robust anyway

Comment: @Yaro working now a little bit in a new one, just with Euclid and Descartes sitting beside me :). Seems more robust and predictable ... and easy.

Comment: well, I may use it if it's robust/fast enough to work on http://yaroslavvb.com/upload/save/blog-barleyTreeSimple.nb The picture is basically a bunch of thick line objects, getting a vector version of that, with smooth joins, is a work in progress

Comment: @Yaro Posted an update with the new approach ... still in progress

Answer (score 2):

## Using only Geometry

---

Of course this one should be able to defeat using ol' Cartesian geometry. The only problem is that there are a lot of arcs and intersections to calculate.

I made an approach. The limitation is that it doesn't handle yet "branched" lines (trees, for example).

Some examples:

[image]

The calculation is instantaneous, but the code is a mess.

```
k[pp_] := Module[{ED(*TODO: make all symbols local*)}, (
    (*follows some analytic geometry *)
    (*Functions to calcu|late borderlines*)
    linesIncrUpDown[{x0_, y0_}, {x1_, y1_}] := 
     thk/2 {-(y1 - y0), (x1 - x0)}/ED[{x0, y0}, {x1, y1}];
    lineUp[{{x0_, y0_}, {x1_, y1_}}] := 
     Plus[linesIncrUpDown[{x0, y0}, {x1, y1}], #] & /@ {{x0, y0}, {x1,y1}};
    lineDown[{{x0_, y0_}, {x1_, y1_}}] := 
     Plus[-linesIncrUpDown[{x0, y0}, {x1, y1}], #] & /@ {{x0,y0}, {x1, y1}};
    (*Distance from line to point*)
    distanceLinePt[{{x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y2_}}, {x0_, y0_}] := 
     Abs[(x2 - x1) (y1 - y0) - (x1 - x0) (y2 - y1)]/ED[{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}];
    (*intersect between two lines without overflows for verticals*)
    intersect[{{{x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y2_}}, {{x3_, y3_}, {x4_, 
         y4_}}}] := {((x3 - x4) (-x2 y1 + x1 y2) + (x1 - x2) (x4 y3 - 
          x3 y4))/(-(x3 - x4) (y1 - y2) + (x1 - x2) (y3 - 
          y4)), (-(x2 y1 - x1 y2) (y3 - y4) + (y1 - y2) (x4 y3 - 
          x3 y4))/(-(x3 - x4) (y1 - y2) + (x1 - x2) (y3 - y4))};
    l2C := #[[1]] + I #[[2]] & ; (*list to complex for using Arg[]*);
    ED = EuclideanDistance; (*shorthand*)


    thk = Cases[pp, AbsoluteThickness[x_] -> x, Infinity][[1]];
    lines = Cases[pp, Line[x_] -> x, Infinity][[1]];
    isz = Cases[pp, Rule[ImageSize, x_] -> x, Infinity][[1]];
    (*now get the scale *)
    {minX, maxX} = {Min[#], Max[#]} &@Transpose[lines][[1]];
    (*scale graphDiam +thk= isz *)
    scale = (isz - thk)/(maxX - minX);
    (*calculate absolute positions for lines*)
    absL = (lines) scale + thk/2;
    (*now we already got the centers for the circles*)
    (*Calculate both lines Top Down*)
    luT = Table[Line[lineUp[absL[[i ;; i + 1]]]], {i, Length[absL] - 1}];
    luD = Table[Line[lineDown[absL[[i ;; i + 1]]]], {i, Length[absL] - 1}];
    (*Calculate intersection points for Top and Down lines*)
    iPuT =Table[intersect[{luT[[i, 1]], luT[[i + 1, 1]]}], {i,Length@luT - 1}];
    iPuD =Table[intersect[{luD[[i, 1]], luD[[i + 1, 1]]}], {i,Length@luD - 1}];

    (*beware drawArc has side effects as modifies luT and luD*)
    drawArc[i_] := Module[{s},
      Circle[absL[[i]], thk/2,
       Switch[i,

        1 , (*first point*)
        If[ ED[absL[[i + 1]],absL[[i]] + {Cos[s = ((#[[2]] + #[[1]])/2)], Sin[s]}] <
            ED[absL[[i + 1]],absL[[i]] + {Cos[s + Pi], Sin[s + Pi]}], # + Pi, #]
            &@{Min@#, Max@#} &@
         Mod[ {Arg[l2C @((luD[[i]])[[1, 1]] - absL[[i]])],
               Arg[l2C @((luT[[i]])[[1, 1]] - absL[[i]])]}, 2 Pi],

        Length@absL,(*last point*)
        If[ED[absL[[i - 1]], absL[[i]] + {Cos[s = ((#[[2]] + #[[1]])/2)], Sin[s]}] <
           ED[absL[[i - 1]], absL[[i]] + {Cos[s + Pi], Sin[s + Pi]}], # + Pi, #] 
           &@{Min@#, Max@#} &@
         Mod[{Arg[l2C @((luD[[i - 1]])[[1, 2]] - absL[[i]])], 
              Arg[l2C@((luT[[i - 1]])[[1, 2]] - absL[[i]])]}, 2 Pi],

        _,(*all middle points*)
        (* here I must chose which lines to intersect luD or luT.
        the correct answer is the line farthest to the previous point*)


        If[
         distanceLinePt[luD[[i, 1]], absL[[i - 1]]] > 
         distanceLinePt[luT[[i, 1]], absL[[i - 1]]],
         (*shorten the other lines*)
         luT[[i - 1, 1, 2]] = luT[[i, 1, 1]] = iPuT[[i - 1]]; lu = luD;
         ,
         (*shorten the other lines*)
         luD[[i - 1, 1, 2]] = luD[[i, 1, 1]] = iPuD[[i - 1]]; 
         lu = luT;];
        (If[ED[absL[[i - 1]], absL[[i]] + {Cos[s = ((#[[2]] + #[[1]])/2)], Sin[s]}] <
            ED[absL[[i - 1]], absL[[i]] + {Cos[s + Pi], Sin[s + Pi]}], {#[[2]]-2 Pi, #[[1]]}, #]) 
          &@{Min@#, Max@#} &@
         {Arg[l2C @((lu[[i - 1]])[[1, 2]] - absL[[i]])], 
          Arg[l2C@((lu[[i]])[[1, 1]] - absL[[i]])]}
        ] ] ];
    );
   Graphics[{Black, Table[drawArc[i], {i, Length@absL}], Red, luT, Blue, luD},
     ImageSize -> isz] ];
```

Test drive

```
isz = 250;
pp[1] = Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[50], JoinForm["Round"], 
    CapForm["Round"], Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}}]}, 
   ImageSize -> isz];
pp[2] = Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[50], JoinForm["Round"], 
    CapForm["Round"], 
    Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, -1}, {0.7, -1}, {0, -4}, {2, -3}}]}, 
   ImageSize -> isz];
pp[3] = Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[50], JoinForm["Round"], 
    CapForm["Round"], 
    Line[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {2, 0}, {2, 3}, {5, 5}, {5, 1}, {4, 
       1}}]}, ImageSize -> isz];
pp[4] = Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[50], JoinForm["Round"], 
    CapForm["Round"], 
    Line[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}, {1/2, 0}}]}, 
   ImageSize -> isz];
GraphicsGrid[Table[{pp[i], k@pp[i]}, {i, 4}]]
```

Comment: Looks cool, but probably an overkill for this particular task and not general enough for the overall visualization I need to do. A general routine might take a set of points and find the smallest smooth shape (bounded curvature of edge) that includes all those points.

Comment: @Yaro Ok, the general routine is left as an exercise for the reader :)

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, just addressing your rasterization comment.

I think this may be faster (0.1 secs for an imagesize of 500 in my machine)

```
pp = Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[100], JoinForm["Round"], 
    CapForm["Round"], Line[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}}]}, ImageSize -> 200];

ColorNegate@MorphologicalPerimeter@pp
```

[image]

BTW I was trying "Export" with all vector image formats and surprisingly the rounded forms are lost in most of them, with the exception of the PDF format, which is useless because it recover the same line definition when importing.

Comment: I've never really done any rastorized image work in mma... `MorphologicalPerimeter` is quite a nice command.

Comment: @Simon Look at this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3983613/find-tunnel-center-line/4013342#4013342